# MonetaryAmount with fixed scale

Tags: java, currency, java-money, mathcontext

In my application at hand, I have to work with a REST/JSON API that expects monetary values of a given maximum scale; e.g.; all monetary values exchanged via this web API must have at most, say, four decimal digits.

To implement the API, I use Kotlin data classes in which I represent monetary values using the `Money` implementation of the  JSR-354 MonetaryAmount API. Is there a possibility to customize the money type to accept a certain maximum scale only and fail otherwise?

That is, when creating a monetary value from a number or string, like `Money.of("200.20234", "EUR")` I would like this construction to fail when the input has more than the admissible number of decimal digits. Similarly, I would like arithmetic operations to fail if they result in more decimal digits than prescribed; e.g., when calculating a percentage of the given monetary value, where the resulting value would result in more decimal digits than configured. Neither do I want implicit rounding nor automatic scale extension (more decimal digits). Is there a way to configure a `MonetaryContext` or underlying `MathContext` to achieve this?

Comment: So instead of retuning silently `Money[200.20 EUR]` you want to reject it?

Comment: yes, exactly, this is what I would like to get as result. Plus the guarantee that any arithmetic operations on the thus-constrained monetary type also either result in values with at most the prescribed number of decimal digits or throw instead.

Comment: take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That is, when creating a monetary value from a number or string, like Money.of(200.20234, "EUR") I would like this construction to fail when the input has more than the admissible number of decimal digits.

I'm interpreting your question as: "I would like problematic inputs to be rejected". Taking that very slight step in the dark, then we have a problem:

**Your entire API is fundamentally broken here** - `double` just **cannot** be the way to convey monetary units, period.

`double`s are represented by 64 bits. That means, by fundamental informatic principles, there are only *at most* 2^64 (that's a number with ~19 digits) unique values that double could possibly represent. And that's a problem; the number line that doubles are designed to represent have an infinite number of values between 0 and 1, let alone between minus infinity and plus infinitive, and 'an infinite amount of values' is **a lot** more than '1000000000000000000 values'.

The way `double` solves this seeming mathematical impossibility is via the blessing system: A specific set of numbers (Slightly less than 2^64 of em) are 'blessed' - representable as `double` values. All other numbers aren't blessed. `double` math works by silently rounding every non-blessed value to its nearest blessed value, every time, at every step, silently, and without any possibility to report on when this occurs or by how much the number is being rounded (after all, the amount it was rounded by is itself unlikely to be blessed either).

Blessed numbers aren't uniformly distributed; there are as many between 0 and 1 as there are between 1 and infinity, for example. As you move away from 1, there are fewer and fewer. Around 2^52, the distance between 2 blessed numbers **is larger than 1**. This all results in silent errors. Here are 2 specific examples that should immediately convince you that any attempt to mention `double` in the same project as "money" is best countered by immediately running for the hills, **you WILL MESS UP if you ever do this**, the only answer is to completely ditch that constructor:

```
System.out.println("Did you know 0.1 * 10 is not equal to 1.0?");
double v = 0.0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) v += 0.1;
System.out.println("Here, have a look: " + (v == 1.0));
// The above prints FALSE!

long z = 123456789123456789L;
double x = z;
System.out.println("Did you know adding 1 to a number doesn't do anything?");
double y = x + 1;
System.out.println("Here, have a look: " + (x == y));
// The above prints TRUE!
```

There are no exceptions and no methods you can use that easily detect 'uhoh, due to rounding-to-nearest-blessed-number, a rather significant error has been introduced'.

Specifically for your case, the key question you have to ask yourself is:

- What is the smallest amount of money such that representing that in the form of a double will get auto-rounded to a different amount of money? - and the answer is probably something around 1234567891234567.89:

```
double z = 1234567891234567.89;
System.out.printf("%.2f\n", z);
```

This prints: 1234567891234568.00

**SILENTLY!**

Hence, we get to the conclusion:

**If you want this method to reject unsafe input, you need to reject a lot more than any number with more than 2 fractional digits**.

### So what do I do instead?

Ditch `double` entirely. All monetary units have an atomic unit. For euros and dollars, it's called a 'cent'. For yen it's simply yen. For pounds, its pennies. For bitcoin, its satoshis. For the indian rupee, its paisa (100 paisa = 1 rupee). And so on.

Most systems are not capable of representing half of an atomic unit. For example, you simply cannot transfer half a cent to a bank account. Hence, *the best way to do currency in any application is to limit all operations to this atomic unit* - i.e. if you are writing software to divide an account's balance amongst 3 accounts (say, that account is jointly owned and is being disbanded), and it contains 1 euro, the answer is **not** to give everybody 33 + 1/3 of a eurocent. The answer is instead one of the following:

- Everybody gets 33 cents; the bank keeps 1 cent.
- Everybody gets 34 cents; the bank loses 2 cents.
- The bank uses a random algorithm to choose an arbitrary owner. They get 34 cents; the other 2 get 33 cents.
- Same as above but instead the account with the lowest account number 'wins' and gets that final cent.
- The process (e.g. some form submission on a website - the 'disband this account and distribute all funds equally to its owners according to their share' button) should crash, telling the user that this operation cannot be done; they will have to ensure the amount available is exactly divisible amongst the accounts.

Nothing, not even `BigDecimal`, can automate this for you: You'd have to write it.

Hence, the best way to represent monetary amounts is usually **as a `long`** or possibly, if you want to represent trillions upon trillions, as a `BigInteger`. Common advice is to use `BigDecimal` - this advice is generally wrong. It's very complex to do this and doesn't get you much: You can now represent half a cent but you've now kicked the can down the road in two ways:

- This does not solve the issue where any interaction with any other system cannot deal with fractions of cents, so you have to round at that point - you haven't gotten around the need to decide on algorithms to deal with fractionals at all.
- BigDecimal can't deal with a third of a cent either (try it - divide 1 by 3 in BigDecimal. That operation crashes unless you specify a rounding mode, in which case you're **still** rounding. If you're going to round, round to the atomic unit).

The only place BigDecimal should come in for monetary stuff is if you really really know what you are doing and have a well defined sensible need + process to represent fractions of atomics, or, very large factors; for example, in foreign exchanges, it can make sense to go from `long` (containing eurocents) to a BD value, multiply it by the foreign exchange rate (also a BD instance), then go back to cents, rounding as the bank's processes explain (presumably, round in the bank's favour).

Thus:

```
Money m = Money.of(12345, Currency.EUR);
System.out.println(m);
```

should be your API, that should print: `"€123.45"`, and your API's signature is:

```
public static Money of(long units, Currency currency)
```

Where `Currency` is an enum or similar concept that encodes for example how many atomics per unit, and how to render them. As an example of this, it is customary in india to render e.g. a million rupee as:

```
₹10.00.000
```

You'd have to encode that logic with the currency, you can't write a single generalized method that can do this.

Comment: Isn't just doing arithmetic problematic when handling doubles? If a system sends 0.3 it is representable with precisely `0.3` in Java.

Comment: It is not. 0.3 is not representable precisely as 0.3. Here's the math behind that: Think of writing 1/3 in decimal. You can't: it's 0.3333 repeating. But 0.8 is fine (0.125), as is, say, 1/25 (0.04). Given that we count in decimal, and 10 has factors 2 and 5, any divisor that consists solely of 2s and 5s 'works'. Hence 25 works (`5*5`), as does 8 (`2*2*2`). But not 3, or even 15 (`3*5`). Computers count in decimal, so only powers of 2 work in the divisor. 8 works (`2*2*2`) - 0.125 is perfectly representable in a double. But 3, which is 3/10, __does not__.

Comment: java seems to 'work' with 0.3 but it really doesn't - try adding 0.3 a bunch of times and will not work (Just like how in this answer, adding 0.1 to a double 10 times doesn't produce 1.0). Repeat that with adding .125 to a double 8 times and that _does_ work. `System.out.println` will slightly round which explains why `double v = 0.3; System.out.println(v);` prints 0.3. __But this is a lie__ - v is really almost but not quite 0.3.

Comment: Isn’t using `long` also kicking the can down the road?  Either you use the implicit rounding of long math operations, or you have to specify rounding in a MathContext with BigDecimal.  I don’t understand how long is significantly better than BigDecimal.

Comment: @VGR It isn't; quite the opposite. For any operation that requires some form of division, you have to deal with the fact that the end result of this operation _has to_ fit in whole cents. For example, an algorithm that distributes the final cent via randomness must be programmed there. Instead of being able to handwave it away by using fractions of cents and worrying about rounding issues later.

Comment: I don't see where the OP said they were using floating point for currency...

Comment: @JimGarrison It's literally in their one snippet: `Money.of(200.20234, "EUR")`. Even if they convert this double into something suitable ASAP, 'reject dangerous input' requires all this background on why `double` is _very_ incompatible with the notion of representing a monetary amount.

Comment: @rzwitserloot Of course floating point should ***never*** be used for money. However, I saw that as the OP just using a shorthand example of a number with too many decimals.  The post contains no mention of floating point, and the use of `BigDecimal` is strongly implied by the reference to `MathContext`, which applies only to `BigDecimal`.  I.e. the wall of text you posted (while they're all good arguments) doesn't answer the OP's actual question.

Comment: I'm not so sure, @JimGarrison - even if they are indeed using BigDecimal and this is just context, the question is then __exactly__ what this wall of text strongly suggests you do: __Ditch `BigDecimal`__. BigDecimal's only major upside (amongst many, many downsides), is the ability to rep fractions of atoms. If OP specifically doesn't want that - stop using BD.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my original question: I am not using double for monetary values, exactly for that reason. Instead, I want to use the JSR-354 monetary type, which is designed explicitly for monetary values. What I am looking for is how to configure this type to constrain the number of decimal digits it uses. There are several implementations of JSR-354, one that relies on BigDecimal internaly (called `Money`), and one that uses Long (called `FastMoney`).

Comment: I don't think the `Currency` class should be responsible for how to render amounts. As you say, 1 million rupees is usually rendered as `₹10.00.000` _in India_. But this rendering is actually a function of the Locale. If you see a mention of 1 million rupees in a British newspaper, it will be written as `1,000,000 rupees`. If you see a mention of 1 million dollars in an Indian newspaper, it will be written as `$10.00.000`. So just let the Locale take care of that.

Comment: I am not talking about the rendering the amount, but about constraining the internal representation to use a fixed amount of decimal digits only.

Comment: @UlrichSchuster The answer explains it. `long` - Money/FastMoney don't appear all that useful if you don't want sub-atomic amounts.

Answer (score -1):

I know of no build-in ultility method/class which does that.
When the input comes as a String I would just verify it with a regex.

```kotlin
object VerifyDecimals {
    private val VALID_MONEY_FORMAT = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\.\\d{4}")
    fun tryParse(input: String): Money {
        require(VALID_MONEY_FORMAT.matcher(input).matches()) { "$input had an invalid format" }
        val context: MonetaryContext = MonetaryContext.from(
            MonetaryAmountFactoryQueryBuilder.of()
                .setMaxScale(4)
                .build(), FastMoney::class.java
        )
        return Money.of(input.toDouble(), "EUR", context)
    }
}
```

This checks that the input contains exactly 4 decimals. And when the double parsing fails, e.g. it is too large it will throw.

Also remember to get the value by calling the `number` property which returns a `javax.money.NumberValue`, because the toString omits decimals beyond the 2nd digit.